# No primary key or unique index found?

Tags: geoserver, oracle-spatial

I have a store created from oracle database in geoserver. Now after I create layer out of the store. And when I try to access the layer or try to preview the layer, I get the warning message in console as

> No primary key or unique index found for 'mylayer'

I see in oracle db, i have created the primary key and I have an index too.
Can anybody suggest, what I am doing wrong, or am I missing something to setup in geoserver?
I see the option

> Primary key metadata table

while creating datastore. Is it anything to do with warning I am getting?

Thanks

Comment: As I'm experiencing the same issue: did you find a solution? Thanks!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 2):

you need specify **sortby** parameter

```
http://example.com/geoserver/wfs?
   service=wfs&
   version=2.0.0&
   request=GetFeature&
   typeNames=namespace:featuretype&
   count=N&
   sortBy=attribute
```

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html#getfeature